Calibrating a high-capacity battery in Android
Good day. Installed a new NOHON BN59 5000mAh battery in Xiaomi PocoF3 phone (original battery 4520mAh). According to the Aida64 application, the battery charges up to 100% (4400-4500mAh) and continues to charge the battery to approximately 4900mAh and more... However, as soon as the charging current drops indicating the end of the charge, the remaining capacity readings reset to the standard value of 4250mAh. I can't understand why the phone doesn't want to recognize the full capacity of the new battery. After all, earlier, when the phone was new, the same Aida64 saw the capacity of the original battery not as 4520mAh, but as 4700mAh and even slightly more... Well, such things happen with new batteries, when the capacity is slightly higher than typical. And now, with a new battery, it doesn't even want to recognize anything above 4600mAh. It charges to nearly full capacity and that's what it shows, but as soon as the current drops to 0.5mAh, the battery value displayed is 4535-4550mAh. Editing the Framework in the offer folder doesn't help solve this issue.
I'm using the native Miui14 Android 13. Could the operating system eventually understand that there is already a 5000mAh battery in the phone? Do I need to do something? Maybe reflash the phone? I've changed MIUI kernels, but it doesn't help.

Does this answer your question? Battery for Samsung Galaxy S8
